# SQL filter on group

Tags: sql

i hava a sql table. The structure is something like SDNR, KPI and Date.

I would like to have all SDNRs whose KPI is not 4 on the earliest date. Better the first SDNR is not 4.

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One method is aggregation, using a `having` clause to determine if the minimum date on a `4` is the overall minimum date:

```
select sdnr
from t
group by sdnr
having min(case when kpi = 4 then date end) is null or  -- no "4" at all 
       min(case when kpi = 4 then date end) <> min(date);
```

The second condition is checking that the value is not `4` on the minimum dates.  The first is just checking whether any `4` exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the quick help.

However, I do not want to sort out the whole group of sdnr's.

I want to sort out tactually only one line with the SDNR.